# How to catch an error on SCNReferenceNode.referenceURL property (SceneKit)?

Tags: swift, scenekit

The problem is that if I create `SCNReferenceNode` and try to get `referenceURL`

```
...
        let refNode: SCNReferenceNode = SCNReferenceNode()
        let curUrl = refNode.referenceURL
...
```

in order to check if it is `nil`, I got an exception

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x186d06dd0)

And looks like there is no way to work around this.

**P.S.** I know there is an option to give an URL to the constructor like `SCNReferenceNode(myURL)`, but I have to use an approach where I create `SCNReferenceNode` before then `refURL` is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the reference URL property should be marked as nullable in the Objective-C implementation, which would make the property an optional, but that isn't the case. Any attempt to access it via the `referenceURL` property will cause a crash, as you've found.

However, since the node is an `NSObject`, you can use key-value coding, and add an extension to it, like this:

```
extension SCNReferenceNode {
    var optionalReferenceURL: URL? {
        value(forKey: "referenceURL") as? URL
    }
}
```

This will give you safe access to the reference URL property. In the meantime, you should also file this as a bug with the SceneKit team.